# Having trouble with Array Appending

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I feel kinda silly being stuck on something that seems so simple for so long but since Im about to put my head through the wall, I figured I'd ask for some help.

I have a loop that splits my data into smaller subsets and loops through each one. For each loop, it produces a `y_test` and a `y_pred` array. It'll be variable size but the shape is (X,). In order to plot the the two arrays vs each other, i just assigned the arrays to an empty dataframe and just used `matplotlib` to plot.

Now, i'd like to just be able to also keep a running total of the `y_pred` and `y_test` so I can see a plot of the entire data set.

**What I've tried:**

Initially, I just tried creating another empty data frame outside my loop and thought to just append the arrays to the end of my columns of the dataframe but i found appending arrays to dataframe was not possible.

Then i thought I'll just append to an empty array for each time through the loop and convert to a dataframe at the end to plot but Im not having much luck there either and if I understand correctly - `np.append` is creating a new array of the appended data every time I append? Wasn't sure if this would get memory intensive.

I was wondering what is the best way to do this?

Here is my code (I tried to remove a lot of the lines that weren't necessary to the problem to make it easier to follow):

```
continuous_results = pd.Dataframe()
        tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=self.no_splits)
        for train_index, test_index in tqdm(tscv.split(X)):
            X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
            y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]



            self.regressor.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

            # predict y values
            y_pred = self.regressor.predict(X_test)


            # plot y_pred vs y_test
            y_df = pd.DataFrame()
            y_pred = y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred), )
            y_test = y_test.reshape(len(y_test), )
            y_df['y_pred'] = y_pred
            y_df['y_test'] = y_test
# failed attempts at continuous dataframe
            continuous_results = continuous_results['Model'].append(y_pred[:,:])
            continuous_results = continuous_results['Actual'].append(y_test)


            y_df.plot()
```

Comment: `np.append` is a just a cover function for `np.concatenate`.  It makes a new array each time, so is slow when used repeatedly.  It's also hard to use correctly (what is the right 'empty' array to start with?).  Usually it's better to collect the results in a list (list append is efficient), and turn that list into an array at the end.  `concatenate` takes a list of arrays, where as `append` just works with 2.

Comment: the problem i have is that my function i'm using that predicts the data generates arrays. So you're saying convert the array to a list and concatenate each time through the loop?

Comment: would you use np.array.tolist to do that?

Comment: Just append the arrays to a list, and do one concatenate, or `stack` at the end

Comment: wouldn't i have to convert each array to a list first then append to my list?

Comment: A list can hold any kind of object, not just other lists.  Experiment.

Comment: when i do that and append to my dataframe it just gives me 1 cell of the data frame that contains a list of all the values. any help with the actual code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: essentially - i need to figure out how to take a list of multple arrays and convert that into a single column of a datafram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create DataFrames from numpy arrays and vice versa:

```
# If you already have data as an array
data = np.random.random((10,5))
# Create a dataframe from a numpy array
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Create a numpy array from a dataframe
as_array = df.to_numpy()
```

If you want/have to loop, you can do this with both numpy arrays and DataFrames. It is more efficient to construct a numpy from a list than to concatenate arrays in a loop:

```
# Looping - arrays can handle n dimensions
data = []
for i in range(10):
    row = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1))
    # Add a second dimension
    row = row[:,np.newaxis]
    # Remove the second dimension
    row = row[:,-1]
    # A list can hold anything
    data.append(row)
# Construct an array from a list of arrays
array = np.array(data)
```

DataFrames can do this as well, but a dataframe row can only have one dimension.

```
# looping - dataframes can work with only one dimension per row
data = []
for i in range(10):
    data.append(np.random.random(5))
# Construct a DataFrame from a list of values
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In order to append to an existing DataFrame, a Series or a DataFrame needs to be created from the data first.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):
    n = np.random.random(1)
    # To append to a DataFrame, first create a Series (a row or a column) or a DataFrame
    row = pd.Series(n, name=i)
    # append a Series (or a DataFrame) to the "bottom" of another DataFrame
    df = df.append(row)
```